# What happens during the iOS Splash Screen?

Tags: ios, splash-screen

When you start an iOS App, you often see the Splash Screen, or Launch Image.

Which of the initialization steps happen during this screen?

What can you control during this phase?

How can you shorten the time the screen is displayed?

Our app takes a long time to load (especially the first time). Ideally I'd like to put some kind of progress bar instead of a static image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The launch screen is show when iOS loads you app into memory. There is nothing you can control will this is happening.

After loading the `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is called in your `main.m`, this will load an `UIApplication` and set your appdelegate as its delegate. After which `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` is called and you have control over what happens from this point on.

The launch screen will be removed as soon as you return `YES` form `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

If your app is taking a long time to load, you should exit form `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` as soon as possible, any resource that need to be load you could dispatch in a queue running in the background this way your app will become active sooner and load data without block any UI thread.

Comment: I NEEDED THIS...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

System needs to load your main view during that time, to shorten the time, please do as little as possible in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, so that your first view controller to be displayed asap, then display a progressive view on your first screen